# EXCEL Copy & Concatenate from one document to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vba

I am having trouble figuring out how to reformat an exel sheet into 4 different sheets.
As of now, I have to documents, one with data and one that needs the others' data reformatted.

Here is the background:

1. The first document has a 48 rows *(groups of 4)* for each (12)month of the year
2. The according columns are from the years 2012-1950
3. *ex.-->* First row is JANUARY with precipitation values for years 2012, then 2011, 2010, etc.
4. *ex.-->* Second row is JANUARY with maxTemp values for the same years
5. The third row is the same with minTemp and the fourth avgTemp; then these 4 are repeated 12 times
6. I need to copy & concatenate all of the months for one data type
7. (in reverse order so that the data is instead from Jan1950-Jan2012)
8. And paste it into a new row in 1 of 4 excel docs (one for each data type)
9. So that one final row will contain *ex precipitation* Jan1950, Feb1950, March1950 ... Nov2012, Dec2012
10. This way, one row will have 12(months)*62(years) IN ORDER from Jan1950 to Dec 2012
11. Basically there will be 4 excel documents each with one really long row

---

Here are my thoughts

(Unless there is a better way) I was wondering if there is a macro (or a formula) that will:

1. Take part of a row in reverse order (ie. Z3-C3) *corresponding to Precip of Jan1950-Jan2012*
2. Copy it and concatenate it with...
3. The same part of another row in reverse order (ie. Z7-C7) *corresponding to Precip of Feb1950-Feb2012*
4. Another row in reverse order (ie. Z12-C12) *corresponding to Precip of Mar1950-Mar2012*
5. Repeat for all 12 months
6. paste them into the precipitation excel document
7. This needs to be done for all four data types (ie. Z4-C4 is minTemp Jan 1950-2012; Z8-C8 Feb; etc.)

*which once again yields, one row with data from Jan1950-Dec2012 for just that data type*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I have tested the VBA Method below and it fails (for me) due to a column limitation, so unless you have a 64bit version (or possibly a version later than 2003) of excel you wont be able to do it using columns. I have modified the VBA version to use rows instead of columns and it works fine.

I've made a demo of both versions here : https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14854735/ptdata.xls

**VBA Method (easy/quick)**

The following is untested. Create a copy of your workbook to work on, open the code editor and paste the following into a new code module (not the workbook or worksheet code sections).

```
Const ROW_HEADER = 1 ' No Row Header - Set to 0
Const COL_HEADER = 1 ' No Column Header - Set to 0

Sub FormatDocument()
' This sub assumes the following
' Your source worksheet has column headers (row 1)
' Your source worksheet has row headers (column 1)
' So your data is bound by the range $B$2:$BL$49
' See above constants if this is not the case
' Your source sheet must be the active sheet when you run this sub (unless you edit below)
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Destination As Worksheet

Dim Pass As Integer
Dim CYear As Integer
Dim CMonth As Integer
Dim Column As Integer

Set Source = Thisworkbook.ActiveSheet ' If possible change this to the name of the source sheet

For Pass = 1 To 4
    Set Destination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Column = 1
    For CYear = (63 + ROW_HEADER) To (1 + ROW_HEADER) Step -1
        For CMonth = 0 To 11
            Destination.Cells(Column, 1).Value = Source.Cells(COL_HEADER + Pass + (CMonth * 4), CYear).Value
            ' NOTE: I've switched the row and column
            ' It will now use many rows and a single column
            ' Destination.Cells(1, Column).Value = Source.Cells(COL_HEADER + Pass + (CMonth * 4), CYear).Value
            Column = Column + 1
        Next
    Next CYear
Next Pass

End Sub
```

**Formula Method**

the following formula should be pasted into your destination sheet(s) and copied across into all required cells (after modifying it to take the desired value type). this is essentially mapping a 2-d array (your data) onto a 1-d array.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(((((COLUMN()-1)-(12*INT((COLUMN()-1)/12))))*4)+2,64-INT(COLUMN()/12),1,TRUE,"SourceSheet"))
```

I've updated the formula and it should now work as expected, however is still limited by column count (Jan1950-Apr1971 is as much as I could get in)

This code should also take column and row headers into account, if you do not need them then `+1+n` becomes `+0+n` and `64-INT(COLUMN()/12)+1` becomes `64-INT(COLUMN()/12)+0`
.
Hint for future questions: If you've tried to make a solution yourself (actual code or formula, not just an outline) you should include it in your question. so we can see you've had a go yourself :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. After trying these, they didn't seem to work but I am messing around with them. Before I try too much & give you results/ask you questions, I wanted to ask... are these two different methods or do they both need to be used? I am new to most of excel so I am unsure.  Also, I would love to send you an image of what it looks like, but I can't post photos. I think that this would be a very easy macro (or formula), I just don't know that much about the syntax yet. Is there a way I can send you an image?

Comment: Its two different methods, thought I said that but can't see where now. The VBA one is a lot easier to use. Does your data have column and/or row headers or is it purely data? The code assumes that range B2:BL49 covers your data, excluding row 1 and column A as they are headers. You might be able to post links to files/pictures, an example of how your data is laid out would be helpful, to make sure I understood correctly.

Comment: Here are some links to the images. Thanks again so much for helping, I think that you are so close, the nested loops just need to be switched a bit. The VBA iterations don't seem to be working correctly though. It's correctly starting all the way at the right (1950), but instead of grabbing all of the values in a ROW, it grabs every fourth in the column, then shifts down to the next column. Here are links to what the tool is doing now and another for what it needs to do. This should make more sense. I removed headers, but the yellow ones are to help you understand what each row & column is.

Comment: Here is the current tool run: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p664ejsdc5qtukq/Current%20Tool%20Run.png?m   here is what the tool needs to do: https://www.dropbox.com/s/utkp12gr8rlwa8i/Desired%20Tool%20Run.png?m so, it's doing the passes correctly, just within there, it's doing down every fourth row by row within column by column... I'm pretty sure these two just need to be switched

Comment: Yeah, your data does not contain row/column headers so its out by one column and one row. the comments in the code say how to fix that (set the constants to zero) I've tested it on my example and it works for me, however you need to be sure that your version of excel can support the required amount of columns (it goes up to column ACB)

Comment: Thanks Nick so much for your help. I was able to do a little editing to the nested loops and found a way that worked. I simply had to put the months loop outside of the year loop. Thanks again!